# url replaced but component not loading in react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am redirecting the application to notfound url from the action if ajax return 401
dispatch(routerActions.push(constant.PREFIX+'notfound/'));
only url updated to /notfound component not loading itself
I have to refresh to load the notfound component.

here is my routes.js file code

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/admin" component={AppBase} onEnter={requireAuth} >
            <IndexRoute component={UsersList} />
            <Route path="users" component={UsersList}/>
            <Route path="product" component={ProductsList}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/admin" component={BasePage}>
            <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
            <Route path="notfound" component={NotFound}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
    </Router>
</Provider>,
```

all routes are working fine expect I redirect it to /notfound from action using

dispatch(routerActions.push('/admin/notfound/'));

here is my action

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { routerActions,push } from 'react-router-redux';

export function fetchData() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch(requestData());
            return axios.get(USER_LIST_URL)
            .then(function(res){
                dispatch(receiveData(res.data));
            })
            .catch(function(res){
                dispatch(receiveError(res.data));
                dispatch(push('/admin/notfound'));
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: I think the issue might be because you have 2 `/admin` routes.

Comment: @Nitsew I will check by changing the /admin route but it was working fine before I migrated application in redux.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @Mr.G
Yes there was some issue with history configuration after redux implementation in My app so I fixed

Comment: What was the fix ?

Comment: @Mr.G It depends upon your code structure.
so Please share your code